# Binary rejected because the application infringes another party's rights

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I just got my app rejected due to violation of rule 8.5. This is the whole message I got in Resolution Center:

> Reasons
>
> 8.5: Use of protected 3rd party material (trademarks, copyrights, trade secrets, otherwise proprietary content) requires a documented
>   rights check which must be provided upon request
>
> 8.5
>
> We have determined that we cannot post your application because it
>   appears to infringe on rights owned by Ravensburger Digital GmbH
>   ("Ravensburger"). Ravensburger objects to applications available in
>   Germany that use the mark Memory in their title and within the
>   application.
>
> Pursuant to the terms of this agreement, you represent and warrant
>   that your application does not infringe the rights of another party,
>   and that you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a
>   claim that your application infringes another party's rights.
>   Moreover, we may reject or remove your application for any reason, at
>   our sole discretion.
>
> Accordingly, please provide documentary evidence that you have the
>   rights to use this content to ensure compliance with the iOS Developer
>   Program License Agreement. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation
>   and confirms its validity, we will proceed with your app review.

Can I resolve the problem by removing Germany from App Store territories without submitting new binary?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly. Are they really saying that a company in germany owns the rights to the word Memory in the titles of apps????

Comment: Hi valheru,
Yes, Ravensburger Digital GmbH owns the rights to the word Memory in the titles of apps.

Comment: Do a Google search on [app title memory german trademark](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=app+title+memory+german+trademark&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=app+title+memory+german+trademark&rls=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from the information you provided, I assume you are creating a game include the word "memory" in the title. It is banned by apple according to this [website](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/11/15/ios_app_store_memory_games_ban/).

This trademark is claimed in the following countries according to the [website](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/11/15/ios_app_store_memory_games_ban/):

> Armenia, Austria, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Belarus, Belgium, Brazil,
>   Croatia, Czech    Republic, Denmark, Egypt, Equador, Estonia, Finland,
>   France, Georgia, Greece, Hungary, India, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein,
>   Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Montenegro, Netherlands, Norway,
>   Peru, Poland, Portugal, Russian Federation, Serbia, Slovakia,
>   Slovenia, South Korea, Spain, Switzerland, Turkey, Ukraine, and
>   Venezuela.

You need to remove it from the countries' App Store listed above.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Your information is useful for me :)

Comment: I think you mean "countries", not "counties".

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I will fix that.

Comment: That are a lot of countries and my country is there also.. Maybe he should rename his app to something original, because you are losing potential marketing sales etc.